# how compare two int[] array for update and merge the difference?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, merge, compare

I wanted to know if there is a simple method to compare two integer array and add in the first array source the missing element in order.

Exemple code :

```
        //Two list [source , compare ]
        public int[] ListSource = new int[]{ 4,8,12,20,24,32 } ;
        public int[] ListToCompare = new int[] { 3, 8, 16, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32,36 };

        //If size of array is different , we resize the source
        if(ListSource.Length != ListToCompare.Length)
        {
            Array.Resize(ref ListSource, ListToCompare.Length);
        }

        // Compare and update
        for(int a = 0 ; a < ListToCompare.Length;a++)
        {
            if(ListSource[a] != ListToCompare[a])
            {
                // .... How can i do it 
            }
        }

        //And finally my Listsource is complete merge with the listToCompare and in good order
        //ListSource = { 3, 4, 8, 12, 16, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32 };
```

Thank's a lot :-)

Comment: Are the inputs guaranteed to be already sorted?

Comment: If those sources are always sorted (so the order is already known), you can `Union` and `OrderBy`. If not - it won't be applicable.

Comment: Should there not be a `36` at the end of your sample answer?

Comment: does the 16 in your result is a misstyping?

Comment: yes sorry it was misstyping about the '16'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Here   is a sample on  how you can achieve this  

 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       //Two list [source , compare ]
    int[] ListSource = new int[]{ 4,8,12,20,24,32 } ;
    int[] ListToCompare = new int[] { 3, 8, 16, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32,36 };


        var res = ListToCompare.Except(ListSource);
        var NewListSource = ListSource.ToList();
        NewListSource.AddRange(res);
       ListSource = NewListSource.OrderBy(x=>x).ToArray();  




        //And finally my Listsou
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid it won't even compile

Comment: in result won't be double 16

Comment: yes but I think it's a misstyping in example given by the user

Comment: doesn't think so, but maybe OP will give us an answer

Comment: so you  think that 36 missing but not 16 is misstyping well :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
ListSource = ListToCompare.Where(x=>!ListSource.Contains(x))
                                .Concat(ListSource).OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
```

check here for result: http://ideone.com/6CY4lp

it will keep the double 16 from example result

Comment: Distinct() is no good - the OP wants to keep BOTH instances of a number if it occurs twice in one of the lists; see the repeated `16` in his sample answer.

Comment: @MatthewWatson ok, thanks I'll change it, now it should return good list

Comment: Seems correct now. I think the OP missed the `36` from the end of his sample answer.

Comment: @MatthewWatson yeah, I think that's a typo.

Comment: thanks it's work fine too . But i can only choose one answer. So thanks again . I up your answer ^^

Answer (score 1):

```
var set = new HashSet<int>();
set.UnionWith(ListSource);
set.UnionWith(ListToCompare);
ListSource = set.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var except = list2.Except(list1);
var result = list1.Union(except).OrderBy(x => x);
```

or short

```
var result = list1.Union(list2.Except(list1)).OrderBy(x => x);
```